# MongoDB Aggregation Error : Invalid reference

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Hello I am getting this error, while running aggregation operation on Collection. I am having this kind of 1000 Entries in FarmerCropDataLog collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c7a590350d039fdc86e4e26"),
    "cropData" : {
        "cropName" : "PADDY",
        "crop" : "PADDY",
        "cropAcres" : 60.0,
        "cropYield" : 21.0,
        "cropPrice" : 6183.0
    },
    "creationTime" : "1551521509924",
    "villageId" : "581edb47e4b0b5b1ebbfe753"
}
```

I want to get Average valud of cropPrice grouped by village. So i wrote following code.

```
public void getComparisonSheet(GetComparisonSheetRequest getComparisonSheet, BasicResponse response,
            String requestFarmerId) {

        Farmer farmer = this.getFarmerById(requestFarmerId);

        // get logs before this year..
        String villageId = farmer.getVillageId();

        MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where(FarmerCropDataLog.Constants.CROP_LOG)
                .elemMatch(Criteria.where(CropData.Constants.CROP).is(getComparisonSheet.getCrop())
                        .and(FarmerCropDataLog.Constants.VILLAGE_ID).is(villageId)
                        .and(FarmerCropDataLog.Constants.CREATION_TIME).gt(LAST_YEAR)));

        GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group(FarmerCropDataLog.Constants.VILLAGE_ID);
        groupOperation.avg(CropData.Constants.CROP_PRICE).as(GetComparisonSheetResponse.Constants.AVERAGE);
        groupOperation.max(CropData.Constants.CROP_PRICE).as(GetComparisonSheetResponse.Constants.MAX_INCOME);

        LimitOperation limitOperation = new LimitOperation(1);

        Fields fields = Fields.fields(GetComparisonSheetResponse.Constants.AVERAGE,GetComparisonSheetResponse.Constants.MAX_INCOME);
        ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project(fields);

        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOperation, groupOperation, projectionOperation,limitOperation);
        AggregationResults<GetComparisonSheetResponse>  aggregationResults = farmerCropDataLogDAO.runAggregation(aggregation, FarmerCropDataLog.class, GetComparisonSheetResponse.class);

        List<GetComparisonSheetResponse> comparisonSheetResponses = aggregationResults.getMappedResults();
        Float AverageIncome = comparisonSheetResponses.get(0).getAverageIncome();
        Float MaxIncome = comparisonSheetResponses.get(0).getMaxIncome();

        GetComparisonSheetResponse comparisonSheetResponse = new GetComparisonSheetResponse();
        comparisonSheetResponse.setAverageIncome(AverageIncome);
        comparisonSheetResponse.setMaxIncome(MaxIncome);

        response.setResponse(comparisonSheetResponse);
        response.setSuccess(true);
    }
```

**This is the error i am getting : Invalid reference 'averageIncome'!**

This is how my FarmerCropDataLog class looks like.

```
public class FarmerCropDataLog extends AbstractEntity {
    private String farmerId;
    private CropData cropData;
    private String villageId;
}
```

This is my CropData class.

```
public class CropData {

    private String cropName;
    private Crop crop;
    private Float cropAcres;
    private Float cropYield;
    private Float cropPrice;
}
```

Comment: can you try it without the alias?

Comment: @HIRATHAKUR, yup. i have removed the projection, then it gives me this error : can't serialize class com.cheruvu.webapp.pojo.Crop

Comment: Your mapping is incorrect. Map your model correctly with respect to db fields.

Comment: First of all, why are you using an elemMatch operator on the nonarray field? Also did you check your query working from mongoshell or not?

Comment: @Mani, yes the query works.

Comment: Did you try convert the query to code in mongodb compass

Comment: No this works. I want this way.